# Why declearing function(Element) outside render doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create a dynamic `Element` inside parent `Component` class. It gives `Unexpected token` at function declaration. However writing same function inside `return(..here..)` works. What am I missing?
This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
var axios = require('axios');

class DisplayRevenue extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[] }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
   this.loadRevenue(this.props.url, this.props.token);
 }

  setData(data){
    this.setState(data:data);
    console.log(this.state.data);    //this gives output as json object
  }

  loadRevenue(url,token){
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
     .then( (response) => {
    //   console.log(response.data);
       this.setData(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Revenue "+error);
     });
  }

  var ListData = this.state.data.map( (invoice) => {return <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>})
//above function gives error

  render() {
    //var listData = this.state.data.map( (invoice) => (<div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>)
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>MonthToDate</h3>
          {this.state.data.map((invoice) => {return <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>})}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayRevenue;
```

I have json object array as below:

```
"data": [
    {
        "customerId": 0,
        "customerNumber": "IT8SDS",
        "customerType": "RVN",
        "invoiceType": "LBR",
        "invoiceAmt": "52651.2287",
        "invoiceStatus": "BILLED",
        "invoiceDate": "2016-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "customerId": 1,
        "customerNumber": "DC0WTY",
        "customerType": "RVN",
        "invoiceType": "RNT",
        "invoiceAmt": "198503.1828",
        "invoiceStatus": "BILLED",
        "invoiceDate": "2016-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "customerId": 2,
        "customerNumber": "LK8MD5",
        "customerType": "INT",
        "invoiceType": "EQT",
        "invoiceAmt": "-6833.70721",
        "invoiceStatus": "PENDING",
        "invoiceDate": "2016-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "customerId": 3,
        "customerNumber": "E03PTJ",
        "customerType": "PCT",
        "invoiceType": "PTS",
        "invoiceAmt": "55670.17911",
        "invoiceStatus": "BILLED",
        "invoiceDate": "2016-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
```

**NOTE:** Writing `{this.state.data.map((invoice) => {return <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>})}` inside return(..here..) in render() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare variables inside a `class` body.
You can do that inside functions (such as render, constructor, react life cycle methods, custom functions etc...).
If you want to do it the "react way" make `ListData` as a component:
Example:

```
const ListData = data => (
  <div>
    {data.map( (invoice) => <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>)}
  </div>
);
```

And use it like so:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>MonthToDate</h3>
        <ListData data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const ListData = ({data}) => (
  <div>
    {data.map((o) => (<div>{o}</div>))}
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <ListData data={["Hi", "i'm", "a", "test"]} />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Doing that gives `Failed to compile` error. `displayRevenue.js: Unexpected token` at `const ListData` ie at declaration of the constant ListData

Comment: i used the es6 arrow function syntax which maybe not supported in your environment.  you can use the normal es5 syntax. i will update the answer.

Comment: No. I am using es6.

Comment: `create-react-app --version` gives **1.4.0**. I think that is the latest. Hence ES6

Comment: where did you declared `ListData` then? not inside the class i hope

Comment: Where do I declare it then? Can we not declare a element inside a component? Is there any way to declare `ListData` as `element`??

Comment: I've added a working example to the answer.  its just a component (`function` or a `class`) you declare it in the same file or a different file (if different file then import it)

Comment: I have declared `ListData` at the bottom of the file ie after `Export` statement. It is giving this error `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.` Hence it cannot detect this function. Is there any way to declare it without creating a new file?

Comment: I just showed you in the snippet. Its declared in the same file.